# WCF POST Method is not working

Tags: c#, json, wcf, fiddler

I have a WCF web service. I want to post some values into MS SQL database using IIS. GET method works. But i can not find where i have mistakes in  my POST method. Does anyone help me about where are my mistakes... Thanks all. Here are my codes...

```
    [OperationContract] //Interface
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddName", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   int AddName(uName name);

     [DataContract]
   public class uName // a class in Interface
    {
        string name;
        [DataMember]
        public string setGetname
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }

public int AddName(uName name) //My POST method in service class
    {

        int state = 0;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {

            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();

            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table_1(kolon1) values(@name)", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.setGetname);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            state = 1;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }


        return state;
    }
```

Comment: You tagged posting with fiddler so I assume you are using fiddler.  Your response is probably coming back with a bad status instead of the 200 Done.  What Error message are you getting?.  Did you try the Insert command in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  Are you getting an error when you connect?

Comment: I changed to parameter uName name to string name and i ran it in WCF Test Serivce, then it worked. It also works in SSMS. But still it does not works on Fiddler. My JSON test string is that : {"sample":"json"} ... Error is bad request: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: HTTP 1.0 is stream mode while HTTP 1.1 is chunk mode.  Chunk mode require after each chunk to send next chunk.  Never got it to work in Net Library.  Usually I force to 1.0 using : request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: it is also  working with that code  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",""); I can not  assign to  passed parameter ...
 Still i couldnt find the solution :(

Comment: First you need to change int rowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteReader(); to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() .Insert will not work if the column is a primary key when the data already exists in database.   If it is in Database then you need to use Update.   To find out if item exist in database fir run either Update or Insert.  Then test rowsChanged.  Insert will return 0 if item exist and then you need to use Update.  Update will return 0 if items is not in database.  Then use Insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED-> I changed to "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare" to "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped" , it worked for me ... Thanks all...